# REST updating multiple resources

Tags: rest

I've tried searching this, but I haven't managed to find an answer which would fit my needs.

Considering I currently have the following route:

```
[GET] /items
```

Which can be filtered by using query parameters. Now I need to give it the ability to add multiple resources at once. I've considered of doing the following request:

```
[PATCH] /items
```

With a body like this:

```
id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3&updateField=newValue
```

I think there is something wrong with this call, but i'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: @hackattack http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789

Comment: PATCH isn't in the standard, is it? I never heard of it. That document is just a proposal.

Comment: PUT is usually used for updating resources.

Comment: I have seen it used before, for example GitHub http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/ scroll down towards the bottom.

Comment: @hackattack technically the entire HTTP specification (and much more) is just a proposal, what do you think RFC stands for?

Comment: @smcg PUT is for PUTting an entire replacement, PATCH is for PATCHing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a RESTful API the URL should define the object of the transaction, and the verb the action.

So `GET /items` should return all items.

`GET /items/1` should return the item with id 1.

It follows that the multiple ids should be part of the resource definition (url). So
`GET /items/1,2,3` should return the 3 appropriate items.

Therefore, to apply a partial update to many ids:

```
[PATCH] /items/1,2,3
```

Then within the body of the PATCH or PUT, you can provide the information to be updated (assuming you are sending a JSON body).

```
{"updateField": "newValue"}
```

Comment: Where you define the list of ids as a wildcard in your route. i.e. routes.Add("/items/{[0-9,]+}", "controller.action") or however the framework that you are using specifies routes. using ASP .NET MVC 3 it would be `context.MapRoute("route_name", "items/{ids}", new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" });`

Comment: I get what you say about `GET /items` returning all the items, but `GET /items?filter=value` can be used to filter such items, right?

Comment: correct, you can add any modifiers you want as query sting parameters. `GET /items?sort=name&search=phillips&page=2&itemsPerPage=10&category=tvs&etc=...`