# Is it a bad practice in RESTFUL architecture, to PATCH to /resources to update multiple documents?

Tags: rest, api

In Restful architectures, it's common to have a PATCH endpoint to /resources/id, to update a single document/entity. Do you think it's a bad practice to have a route to PATCH on /resources to update multiple documents/entities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST updating multiple resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872923/rest-updating-multiple-resources)