# REST: best way to save multiple records of nested resource

Tags: rest, rails-api

In my domain design, one `ElectronicPressKit` can have multiple `TechRiderItem`s.

In the mobile app, there is a screen where multiple `TechRiderItem`s can be added, edited or deleted. On the click of save, these `TechRiderItem`s should be sent to the API which will save them.

I have thought of these options for adding `TechRiderItem`s of an `ElectronicPressKit`

1) On the click of save, the mobile app will send multiple calls to `POST` `/api/electronic_press_kits/:epk_id/tech_rider_items` (i.e: save one record at a time).

2) The mobile app will send one call to `POST` `/api/electronic_press_kits/:epk_id/tech_rider_items` passing multiple `TechRiderItem`s in the payload.

3) The mobile app will send one call to `PATCH` `/api/electronic_press_kits/:epk_id` passing multiple `TechRiderItem`s in the payload.

Which is the best way according to `REST`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST updating multiple resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872923/rest-updating-multiple-resources)

Comment: As well as previous SO answers (such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872923/rest-updating-multiple-resources),  you may find some benefit in this article: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/implementing-bulk-updates-within-restful-services/